# Items in view not appearing on load

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to load another view when I click on one of my `UITableCell` view, but none of the things that are on the xib file (associated with that view) are showing.

This is how I'm initializing the view (in the controller that generates the `tableView`):

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = @"Cards";
        self.detailController = [[BasicCardViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"CardView" bundle:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is where I deal with the selection:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary *component = self.resultsTuples[indexPath.row];

    [AJAXUtils getAsyncJsonWithUrl:(NSURL *)[NSURL URLWithString:someUrl]  callback:^(NSDictionary *returnjson) {
        if (returnjson != nil) {
            NSString *userPageLink = returnjson[@"Node"][@"SessionInfo"][@"PostingAs"][@"Key"];
            self.detailController.userPageLink = userPageLink;
            self.detailController.nodePage = returnjson[@"Node"][@"Key"];

            NSString *selectedCard = component[@"$element"][@"Title"];
            [self.detailController setDescription:component[@"element"][@"ContactCard"][@"Description"]];
            [self.detailController setPageTitle:selectedCard];
            self.detailController.title = selectedCard;

            NSString* rating = component[@"$element"][@"Summary"][@"AverageRating"];
            self.detailController.rating =(NSInteger)rating;
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailController animated:YES];
        }
    }];
}
```

This is my **`BasicCardView`** code -

```
@implementation BasicCardViewController
@synthesize userPageLink = _userPageLink;
@synthesize nodePage = _nodePage;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    _trendingImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trending.png"];
}

- (UILabel *)label {
    return (id)self.view;
}

- (void)loadView {
    self.rateView = [[RateView alloc] init];
}

- (void)setDescription:(NSString *)description {
    _description = description;
    _descriptionView.text = description;
}

- (void)setPageScore:(NSString *)pageScore {
    _pageScore = pageScore;
    _pageScoreLabel.text = pageScore;
}

- (void)setRestaurantImage:(UIImage *)restaurantImage {
    _restaurantImage.image = restaurantImage;
}

- (void)setPageTitle:(NSString *)title {
    _pageTitle = title;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];

    self.rateView.notSelectedStar =[UIImage imageNamed:@"kermit_empty.png"];
    self.rateView.halfSelectedStar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"kermi_half.png"];
    self.rateView.fullSelectedStar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"kermit_full.png"];
    self.rateView.rating = self.rating;
    self.rateView.editable = YES;
    self.rateView.maxRating = 5;
    self.rateView.delegate = self;
    _pageTitleLabel.text = _pageTitle;
}
```

Why is nothing appearing when the cell is clicked?
But if I do `self.view = rateView` in the `viewDidLoad`, the rateView appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view controller calls loadView method when its view property is requested but is currently nil. This method loads or creates a view and assigns it to the view property. And it appeared as if your self.view is nil, in loadView method, you have created self.rateView but hasn't assigned it to self.view to make it visible.

Comment: right..but my view isn't just rate view - there's a bunch of other stuff on it. Rate view is a component of it and my xib file has a bunch of labels and stuff too. I'm calling initWithNibName elsewhere, so self.detailController should be a view controller initialized with that xib file that has the rate view and the labels and other stuff

Comment: Did other views displayed in your view controller?

Comment: If you are loading your view controller's view from nib then load view method is not needed, it will work only when you create the view for view controller programmatically.

Comment: ok...so do I just take out that method? how does that fix the problem?

Comment: You appeared to be missing super call in your viewDidLoad.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43207/discussion-between-ldindu-and-praks5432)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `getAsyncJsonWithUrl` block called  out of the main thread try, to call the `pushViewController` inside the `mainQueue` as following:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailController animated:YES];       
}];
```

Comment: I don't think this is the issue - when I do self.view = self.rateView in the viewDidLoad - the rateView appears.

Answer (score 0):

It may help sometimes.
_detailController = [[BasicCardViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"CardView" bundle:nil];